# Is it legal to name open-source software after established entities? (Bands, video game characters, etc.)

Tags: copyright, trademark

Title says it all - is it legal for me to create an open-source video game engine, or any other open-source software, and name it after an established band, person or video game character?

Comment: Have you looked at the following Q&A's? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/naming-products-after-fictional-objects-or-characters
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/can-i-name-a-real-company-after-a-fictional-company-found-in-a-book
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16208/can-i-use-a-store-name-as-part-of-my-trivia-game

Answer (score -1):

**Looks like I got the answer I needed:**

[image: Looks like I got the answer I needed]

Comment: I suppose this answer has been downvoted because *of course* the trademark owners will tell you that you cannot do this.  That doesn't mean that it's actually illegal.  That depends on what a *court* would say. If everyone accepted the assertions of their opponents' lawyers, there would be no need for judges.